# Passenger can't find bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, passenger, redmine

I am desperatly trying to set up Redmine on my debian server. I managed almost everything (the interface works with webrick), but I want it to be accessable via dev.kaleydra.de, I wanted to solve this by using passenger+the apache2 module.
So now my current status is this message when I visit dev.kaleydra.de

Error message:
Redmine requires Bundler. Please install it with `gem install bundler`.

But bundler is definitly installed! (bundle install worked perfectly)

Some information:

```
 gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /root/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
```

I tried adding this to the enviroment.rb:

```
ENV['GEM_HOME']='/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1'
ENV['GEM_PATH']='/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1'
```

What I might notice is that I can't run 
passenger-install-apache2-module
because it won't let me install libpq5 (Plesk uses a newer version and it specificly requests "libpq5 (= 8.4.13-0squeeze1)" with apt-get), but since passenger is showing the page makes it look like it already works...

I am kind of desperate, any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I need your apache config file.

If you have all the needed gems installed but passenger still complain no gem found, please check if your 'apache user' has the privilege to access the gem folder.

e.g. your gems is installed by root but your apache-user is non-root, then this error occurs.

the solution is quit simply, if there's a account named root (e.g. in Centos) just these lines to your apache config file (httpd.conf or so)

```
User root
Group root
```

more details about "root, apache", see this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/103644/apache-user-root-access